# How to specify the correct USER_ID in analyticsreporting.userActivity.search?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to retrieve data linked to USER_ID by analyticsreporting.userActivity.search of Analytics Reporting API v4 using Google APIs Explorer.
But, when I make a Request body according to the official sample, the result that USER_ID does not exist is returned.

The Request sent and the Response returned are below.
(ViewID was omitted.)

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/userActivity:search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
    "viewId": "(Omitted)",
    "user": {
        "type": "USER_ID",
        "userId": "28"
    },
    "dateRange": {
        "startDate": "2019-05-20",
        "endDate": "2019-05-26"
    }
}
```

```
400

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  114
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 27 May 2019 11:14:44 GMT
server:  ESF
vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "USER_ID: 28 not found.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

The specified USER_ID uses a User-ID value that can be verified in the Google Analytics User Explorer.
I tried to specify numbers such as 1 or 2 and other IDs displayed in User Explorer for the value of USER_ID, but the result was the same.
And I deleted the dateRange but the result was the same.
As with changing the ViewID, the error message is changed to "No permission to view", so the ViewID is not a problem.

Please tell me the correct specification method of USER_ID.

thank you.

Comment: you need to find the user id that you inserted. 28 is not a user id that you sent

Comment: Where should I find the user ID? Should I not use the User Explorer's User-ID value?

Comment: Well seeing as you inserted it from your website i would guess that its the user id from your system however that depends upon how you have set up the User-id tracking code.

Comment: This API was broken.Fixed 2019/12.It's working now. thank you.